# 301 redirect with custom conditions

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect some url with .htaccess file.

Some examples for better understanding,

```
1) http://www.mydomain.com/Salary/Account-Manager-Salary-Jobs 
   to 
   http://www.mydomain.com/Salary/Account-Manager-Salaries

2) http://www.mydomain.com/Salary/Software-Enginner-Salary-Jobs 
   to 
   http://www.mydomain.com/Salary/Software-Enginner-Salaries
```

I want rewrite rule condition with pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in your $DOCUMENT_ROOT and put this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(Salary/.*-Salary)-Jobs$ $1 [L,NC]
```